# Using awk/cut/sed with lines containing different numbers of fields

Tags: unix, sed, awk, cut

I'm using the pinboard.in API to get a list of my current bookmarks. The results look like this:

```
<post href="https://www.nocc.meezy.com/doc/view.cgi?id=715" time="2013-02-11T17:38:10Z" description="Disk Errors Process Flow Chart" extended="" tag="nocc work" hash="a3419515b2e956e86886ba630b6028b7" meta="d793aeef6133a26e361695181eb57b9d"    />
<post href="https://www.nocc.meezy.com/doc/view.cgi?id=39" time="2013-02-11T17:38:08Z" description="Using socat" extended="" tag="socat work" hash="fd60523bf841b2b95674a0e1d4401f4d" meta="5f2b6ad395fe4da05b2987d199b675ea"    />
<post href="https://agora.meezy.com/wiki/Development_Tools" time="2013-02-11T17:38:06Z" description="Development Tools - meezyWiki" extended="" tag="devtools work" hash="dcf904433987a125c00a88bcaf31cad27" meta="5e744562282561390a0417223d323aee"    />
```

I'm only interested in the URL, description, and tags, so I'd like to have the results look like this:

```
https://www.nocc.meezy.com/doc/view.cgi?id=715 description="Disk Errors Process Flow Chart" tag="nocc work"  
https://www.nocc.meezy.com/doc/view.cgi?id=39 description="Using socat" extended="" tag="socat work"  
https://agora.meezy.com/wiki/Development_Tools description="Development Tools - meezyWiki" tag="devtools work
```

I know a little bit about awk/cut/sed but not enough to tell them how to count the fields correctly when the description and tag fields contains spaces and different numbers of strings.

I could probably hack together some really crappy solution if my life depended on it but I'd rather get a proper solution by someone who knows them much better than I do.

Thanks

Comment: It's best not to try to parse XML with sed/awk/cut which aren't the proper tools for the job. This is XML; use an XML parser.

Comment: although as mentioned above - UNIX tools are not a good choice for parsing XML ,however i guess you are writing these in text file and try to list these URLs ?

Answer (score 1):

when you playing with xml with regex/awk/sed.. you should know the risk. here is sed one-liner for your requirement:

```
 sed -r 's/^.*"(http)/\1/; s/" time=.*( desc)/ \1/; s/extended=.*( tag=")/\1/; s/hash=.*//' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  sed -r 's/^.*"(http)/\1/; s/" time=.*( desc)/ \1/; s/extended=.*( tag=")/\1/; s/hash=.*//' file
https://www.nocc.meezy.com/doc/view.cgi?id=715  description="Disk Errors Process Flow Chart"  tag="nocc work" 
https://www.nocc.meezy.com/doc/view.cgi?id=39  description="Using socat"  tag="socat work" 
https://agora.meezy.com/wiki/Development_Tools  description="Development Tools - meezyWiki"  tag="devtools work"
```